# Can't assign the landscape LayerInfo object to a landscape

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've been developing an automated system that requires me to generate the *LayerInfo* objects of a given *Landscape*. So far I've been able to generate the required LayerInfo object's, but I wasn't able to assign them, or to be more precise, when I try to assign the necessary layers in the *ULandscapeInfo*  property they appear in the editor but are not assigned, unless I save them and restart the engine, they also appear weird in the editor, as you can see in the image. I think it's a similar problem to the one in [this thread](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/843624/assign-landscape-layer-info-not-saving.html). The  code bellow it's responsible for assignig the *LayerInfo*:

```
        // This method creates a
        // new layer info object
        UWorld * currentWorld = GetWorld();
        ULevel * level = currentWorld->GetLevel(0); // TODO : just for debuging 
        ULandscapeLayerInfoObject* layerInfo = Landscape->CreateLayerInfo(*(layerName), level);
        bool isDirty = layerInfo->MarkPackageDirty();
    
        // Get a reference for the landscape Info
        ULandscapeInfo* landscapeInfo = Landscape->GetLandscapeInfo();
        landscapeInfo->CreateLayerEditorSettingsFor(layerInfo);
        FLandscapeInfoLayerSettings* layerSettings = &landscapeInfo->Layers[1];
    
        landscapeInfo->Layers[0] = FLandscapeInfoLayerSettings(layerInfo, Landscape);
        UEditorAssetLibrary::SaveAsset(assetName, false);
        
        // Assign the respective values
        if (!layerSettings->LayerInfoObj)
        {
            layerSettings->Owner = Landscape;
            layerSettings->LayerInfoObj = layerInfo;
            layerSettings->bValid = true;
        }
```

[Editor Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXYXy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I replied to the Unreal thread with a solution I have found works for me:

```
InfoObject->LayerName = LandscapeLayerSettings.LayerName;
InfoObject->bNoWeightBlend = false;

if (!LandscapeLayerSettings.LayerInfoObj)
{
    LandscapeLayerSettings.Owner = Landscape;
    LandscapeLayerSettings.bValid = true;
    LandscapeLayerSettings.LayerInfoObj = InfoObject;
    LandscapeLayerSettings.GetEditorSettings().LayerInfoObj = InfoObject;
}
```